# strong typedef of std::string

Tags: c++, string, strong-typedef

## Motivation (Question background)

I use std::string for many meanings.
For example, address and name (in practice more meanings).

Let's say the address and name have a default value.

```cpp
void set_info(std::string address, std::string name) {
    // set address and name
}
void set_info(std::string address) {
    // set address and set default name
}
void set_info(std::string name) {
    // set name and set default address
}
```

The target is not only function but also class constructor.

```cpp
struct info {
    info(std::string address, std::string name)
    : address_{std::move(address)}, name_{std::move(name)}
    {}
    info(std::string address)
    : address_{std::move(address)}
    {}
    info(std::string name)
    : name_{std::move(name)}
    {}
    std::string address_;
    std::string name_;
};
```

However, the latter two overloads are the same(Only difference is parameter name). So I can't do that.

So I come up with strong typedef of std::string helps the situation.

### Additional motivation

If each information has different types, it can avoid accidental type match. I expect that it could help "difficult to misuse" interface.
The motivation is something like Boost.Unit https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_units.html

## Question

Is there any good way to write strong typedef of std::string?

My requirement are here:

1. Can write overloads of multiple strong typedefs.

   ```cpp
   void foo(type1) {}
   void foo(type2) {}
   ```
2. Can operate the same as std::string including helper operators.
   At least operator+() is required.
   The operator should work similar as
   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B
   The return value of the operator+() should be the strong typedef-ed type, not std::string.

I defined the following classes:

```cpp
struct type1 : std::string {
    using std::string::string;
};

struct type2 : std::string {
    using std::string::string;
};
```

It works well for the requirement 1. However, the return type of operator+() is std::string, not strong typedef-ed type.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/6GAlcCoZi8XvumnZ

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct type1 : std::string {
    using std::string::string;
};

struct type2 : std::string {
    using std::string::string;
};

inline void foo(type1 const& v) {
    std::cout << "type1:" << v << std::endl;
}

inline void foo(type2 const& v) {
    std::cout << "type2:" << v << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    type1 t1 = "ABC";
    type2 t2 = "DEF";
    foo(t1);
    foo(t2);

    // The return type of t1 + "123" is std::string, not type1
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t1 + "123"), std::string>);
    // So it is not valid code to call foo(type1 const&)
    // foo(t1 + "123");
}
```

I'm looking for a way to implement the operator+() that satisfies the following code:

```cpp
int main() {
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    type1 m1 = "abc";
    type2 m2 = "def";

    // expected foo(type1 const&) is called
    foo(m1);
    foo(m1 + "a");
    foo("a" + m1);
    foo(m1 + "a"s);
    foo("a"s + m1);

    // expected foo(type2 const&) is called
    foo(m2);
    foo(m2 + "a");
    foo("a" + m2);
    foo(m2 + "a"s);
    foo("a"s + m2);

    std::string s = "a"s + "b"; // not become error
}
```

I tried to implement something like following operator+() but it causes ambiguous overloads.

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline 
std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string> &&
    (!std::is_base_of_v<std::string, std::decay_t<T>> ||
     std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string>),
    type1
>
operator+(type1 lhs, T&& rhs) {
    lhs += std::forward<T>(rhs);
    return lhs;
}

template <typename T>
inline 
std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string> &&
    (!std::is_base_of_v<std::string, std::decay_t<T>> ||
     std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string>),
    type1
>
operator+(T&& lhs, type1 const& rhs) {
    type1 ret{std::forward<T>(lhs)};
    ret += rhs;
    return ret;
}
```

I guess that if I implement all combinations of operator+() overloads for each strong typedef-ed types (type1, type2,...) but I expect that there is better way.

Comment: boost has a strong typedef.

Comment: What is the reason for this "strong typedef"? What is the underlying problem that's supposed to solve? While we can give you hints about your solution, perhaps it's not the only possible solution to that underlying problem? Please always ask about the original problem directly instead of help with a solution to an unknown problem (which makes the question [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: and for the problem at hand, it would help if you include the compiler error message. I tried to stitch the parts together, but I get no error about ambiguity https://godbolt.org/z/KW7ThGTba

Comment: Deriving from `std::string` is a bad thing to do. Is there a good reason to have `void set_info(std::string address)` instead of `void set_address(std::string)`?

Comment: What is the reason why you need overloaded functions that are named the same instead of `void setAddress(std::string address)`, `void setName(std::string name)`?

Comment: I added the constructor case to my question (Motivation part). I want to initialize the member, not assignment.

Comment: If you just want explicit parameter naming at call site, in C++20 you could achieve something like that with a struct InfoParams (or something like that) passed as a parameter and designated initializers for initializing its members.

Comment: note that your motivation does not make above suggestions obsolete. Instead of using a constructor you can use named static functions `constructFromName` and `constructFromAdress`. Just because a constructor creates objects, does not mean that you should not use a non-constructor to construct something

Comment: @Kaznov I've checked https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html But I couldn't find it. Could you tell me the proposal number?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, ah yes, a combination of static member function and full parameter version  constructor can solve the overload problem.

Comment: I added additional motivation. It is not my essential part of the motivation. I'm interested in difficult to misuse interface. Boost.Unit provides that. I expect that strong typedef-ed string can provide the same benefit. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: If you *really* want to use strong-typedef or something, maybe this can help you: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/types/strong_alias.h

Comment: I noticed that if I want to write "difficult to misuse" interface, define the class that has std::string as a member variable. I need to write a series of std::string like member functions (only needed ones) and helper operators (only needed ones). I think that it is not a bad idea.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo It was just idea to use designated initializers, "InfoParams" is just a name I came up with, cause your methods were called "setInfo", and the struct would be just encapsulating the params. You can read anout designated initializers here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need to wrap every operation of std::string because you won't need to use them. All that the caller has to do is initialise the argument with a correct type with a value for the internal string:

```
struct address_type {
    std::string value;
};

struct name_type {
    std::string value;
};

struct info {
    info(address_type address, name_type name)
    : address_{std::move(address.value)}, name_{std::move(name.value)}
    {}
    info(address_type address)
    : address_{std::move(address.value)}
    {}
    info(name_type name)
    : name_{std::move(name.value)}
    {}
private:
    std::string address_;
    std::string name_;
};


info with_address {address_type{"str"}};
info with_name    {name_type   {"str"}};
```

---

But if you want to proceed with your approach of providing string functionality with your custom type, then you must wrap all the operations. That's going to be a ton of boilerplate and there's no magic to avoid that.

Comment: Maybe my comment is misleading. I mean the same approach as your answer. I mean using std::string as member variable of class info **instead of inheriting std::string**.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo Fair enough, I remove that part.

Answer (score 0):

I use private inheritance to achieve this goal. I need to add using statements on base members I want to see public. This can be seen as a burden, or a design advantage by which you can control what you want to expose.
My 2 Cents.