# Making a custom type behave like std::string

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdstring, c++23, value-categories

I have to define a few structs that contain a member of type `std::string`. I need to make them behave like `std::string`. In other words, they should be trivially convertible to `std::string` but not to each other. Instances of these structs will in turn be members of another class:

```
class Foo
{
    Name_t m_name;
    Description_t m_description;
// ...
};
```

Thus a function taking a parameter of type `Name_t` should not be callable with a `Description_t` instance even though they're both `std::string` under the hood.

How can this be achieved in a proper way? I tried overloading the `operator std::string&` for all the those types. It seems to work though. And I am not sure if I should declare them with the `explicit` keyword.

An example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>


struct Description_t
{
    std::string value;

    operator std::string&( ) noexcept
    {
        return value;
    }

    operator const std::string&( ) const noexcept
    {
        return value;
    }
};

bool operator==( const Description_t& lhs, const Description_t& rhs ) noexcept
{
    // This using declaration looks too verbose to my eyes!
    using underlying_type = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<
                              std::add_const_t<
                                decltype( std::declval<decltype( lhs )>( ).value )> >;

    return static_cast<underlying_type>( lhs ) == static_cast<underlying_type>( rhs );
    // return lhs.value == rhs.value; // equivalent to the above statement
}

struct Name_t
{
    std::string value;

    operator std::string&( ) noexcept
    {
        return value;
    }

    operator const std::string&( ) const noexcept
    {
        return value;
    }
};

bool operator==( const Name_t& lhs, const Name_t& rhs ) noexcept
{
    // Again, this using declaration looks too verbose to my eyes!
    using underlying_type = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<
                              std::add_const_t<
                                decltype( std::declval<decltype( lhs )>( ).value )> >;

    return static_cast<underlying_type>( lhs ) == static_cast<underlying_type>( rhs );
    // return lhs.value == rhs.value; // equivalent to the above statement
}

int main()
{
    Description_t stock1 { "Hi!" };
    Description_t stock2 { "Hi!" };
    Name_t name1 { "Hello!" };
    Name_t name2 { "Hello!" };

    assert( name1 == name2 );
    // assert( name1 == stock1 );
}
```

However, in the definition for `underlying_type` I had to do a `static_cast` to `const std::string&` by adding *ref* and *const* to it. Otherwise, the compiler would generate two inefficient copy constructions inside the `operator==` to compare the `value`s of the two `Name_t` arguments. Is there a more concise way of doing this (other than `lhs.value == rhs.value`)?

Also should the `operator==` be a member function in the above cases?

Comment: You answered your own question: a conversion operator. This is what they're for. As far as everything else goes: one question per Stackoverflow question, please. I get the sense that this is an attempt to learn C++ from search engines, blogs, rambling Youtube videos, and by asking one question at a time, instead of learning C++ [from a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68358538 (A more concise `operator==` would be `friend bool operator==(const Description_t&, const Description_t&) = default;`)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok. And is there a better solution to the second problem? I mean something less verbose.

Comment: Which "second problem"? There are many questions here. It would be better to ask one question at a time, please, with each question concisely, and precisely, phrased.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The definition for `underlying_type` doesn't look neat.

Comment: please focus on 1 specifc question. If the answer to that does not explain everything you can ask another question. Asking several quesitons at once makes this question difficult to answer concisely

Comment: Don't worry about it. Just keep on pluggin'. After using and working with C++ for some time, this same definition of `underlying_type` will read like poetry. Did you try reading your favorite C++ template header file?

Comment: How about using (boost) strong_typedef?

Comment: `std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::add_const_t<decltype(...)>>` is always `const decltype(...)&` if the `...` isn't `void`. I think you are just looking for `using underlying_type = decltype((lhs.value))` though (extra brackets will make it `const std::string&`)

Comment: From my own experience (i.e., my opinion), I'd much rather have a `auto to_string() -> std::string` method than a user-defined conversion `operator std::string` that works implicitly.  Even moreso if that conversion is a reference or const-reference.  But if the object is **really really** intended just be be a "denominated string", I'd second Jarod42's suggestion of Boost's strong_typedef.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I wrote that definition myself. I do understand what it does. Hence I'm asking to see if anything shorter can be used there.

Comment: @Jarod42 I should rely on STL only. Maybe next time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a typed string that behaves like a string, CRTP with std::string inheritance would be an option:

```
template <typename>
struct TypeSafeString : std::string {
  using std::string::string;
};

struct Description : TypeSafeString<Description> {
  using TypeSafeString<Description>::TypeSafeString;
};

struct Name : TypeSafeString<Name> {
  using TypeSafeString<Name>::TypeSafeString;
};
```

A `std::string` will always convert to `Description` and to `Name` but no `Description` will convert to `Name` or `std::string` (or vice versa).

As suggested in the comments by 0xbachmann you can be even less verbose by using lambda types instead of CRTP:

```
using Name = TypeSafeString<decltype([]{})>;
using Description = TypeSafeString<decltype([]{})>;
```

But then you wont be able to add custom members, obviously.

Comment: Looks promising. But does this make it possible to have an `operator==` for the types above? I wish you had added that as well. Also, the (explicit) conversion to `std::string&` must be possible since these will have to be passed to functions like `std::getline`.

Comment: @digito_evo Yes, you can explicitly convert to `std::string&` just like any other polymorphy. But make sure you don't slice. And yes `operator==` is relatively easy, depending on which things you want to allow to compare equal. Can you compare a name to a string? Probably not a name to a description. If you only want name to compare to name, you have to write a small function for each derived type. I'll add one to the answer.

Comment: Only name to name.

Comment: @digito_evo Sorry, turns out I was wrong. Seems the distinct types convert too easily back to string so `operator==` for `std::basic_string` always triggers. Good news is that you don't have to do a thing to have it work, bad news is that it means `Name` can be compared to `Description`. If you want to avoid that make the inheritance protected or private and only pick the member functions you really want via `using` (like with the constructor in the code above). Then you will have to write your own `==` in the class template.

Comment: you can get rid of CRTP with using declarations and lambdas: `using Description = TypeSafeString<decltype([]{})>;
using Name = TypeSafeString<decltype([]{})>;` they have unique types

Comment: @0xbachmann Oh, that's cool! Unless one wants to have additional members in the specific types, that is. I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I crafted a solution that satisfies my needs. It's also pretty minimal (both in terms of the number of `#include`s and ease of readability).

Here:

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>


template <typename UniqueType = decltype( []{} )>
struct [[ nodiscard ]] denominated_string_t
{
    std::string value;

    [[ nodiscard ]] constexpr auto&
    to_underlying( ) noexcept
    {
        return value;
    }

    [[ nodiscard ]] constexpr const auto&
    to_underlying( ) const noexcept
    {
        return value;
    }
};

using Name_t = denominated_string_t<>;
using Description_t = denominated_string_t<>;

constexpr bool
operator==( const Name_t& lhs, const Name_t& rhs ) noexcept
{
    return lhs.to_underlying( ) == rhs.to_underlying( );
}

constexpr bool
operator==( const Description_t& lhs, const Description_t& rhs ) noexcept
{
    return lhs.to_underlying( ) == rhs.to_underlying( );
}

int main()
{
    Description_t stock1 { "Hi!" };
    Description_t stock2 { "Hi!" };
    Name_t name1 { "Hello!" };
    Name_t name2 { "Hello!" };

    assert( name1 == name2 );

    // These don't compile which is the expected behavior
    // assert( name1 == "Hello!" );
    // assert( name1 == stock1 );
    // Name_t { stock1 };
    // std::string { name1 };

    std::getline( std::cin, name1.to_underlying( ) ); // Nice and concise!
}
```